# How Tanuro Shel Akhnai was different from the first Machlokes in the Mishnah?

Tags: tractate-brachot, bava-metzia

THe first Mishna presents a Machlokes between R' Eliezer, R' Gamliel and "the rest" of the Chachamim (unclear).

> מֵאֵימָתַי קוֹרִין אֶת שְׁמַע בְּעַרְבִית. מִשָּׁעָה שֶׁהַכֹּהֲנִים נִכְנָסִים לֶאֱכֹל בִּתְרוּמָתָן, עַד סוֹף הָאַשְׁמוּרָה הָרִאשׁוֹנָה, דִּבְרֵי רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר. וַחֲכָמִים אוֹמְרִים, עַד חֲצוֹת. רַבָּן גַּמְלִיאֵל אוֹמֵר, עַד שֶׁיַּעֲלֶה עַמּוּד הַשָּׁחַר.
>
> From what time may one recite the Shema in the evening? From the time that the priests enter [their houses] in order to eat their terumah until the end of the first watch, the words of Rabbi Eliezer. The sages say: until midnight. Rabban Gamaliel says: until dawn.

This disagreement did not lead to any violent clash and disastrous outcomes as in Tanuro Shel Akhnai incident. And R"G seemingly didn't force himself on others.

What is different and why in the first Mishnah there was no need to follow the majority or ask Heaven to testify?

Comment: Seemingly the minority eventually conceded to the majority regarding Shema, unlike Rabbi Eliezer by Tanur shel Achnai where he refused to budge

Comment: I don't think you understand what [tag:halacha-theory] is for. It's not for questions about any discussion in which someone argues; it's for questions about principles of psak.

Comment: @DonielF In this case I'd agree.